# How do I change the default model template in Rails scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffold

If I want to change the default controller template created by scaffold in Rails it's dead easy - after Googling around I found I can just put a controller.rb file in lib/templates/rails/controller for the generator to pick up on instead of the default.

I cannot find any explanation of where I can do the same for a model file.  I don't want to build a separate generator, I just want:

```
> rails generate model foo
```

to create foo.rb model file based on a model.rb template I make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is a great idea but you can find the generator code here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/model/model_generator.rb

```
module Rails
  module Generators
    class ModelGenerator < NamedBase #metagenerator
      argument :attributes, :type => :array, :default => [], :banner => "field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]"
      hook_for :orm, :required => true
    end
  end
end
```

According to [this post](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates) though you should be able to put a template in `lib/templates/rails/model` though you may need to specify where it is located via a rake task according [to this](http://m.onkey.org/rails-templates)

Comment: Yeah, I did try that and it didn't seem to pick any changes up that I made to the model_generator.rb file... maybe I made a mistake somewhere, because that was my thought of how to do this too... or maybe I didn't figure out correctly how to make that generator use my template file (still pretty new with generators).  I will take a fresh look at this solution though, as you're suggesting it.

Comment: Okay... so I took a look at what you reference and the links are to 1) building your own generator and using that, 2) what I mentioned in the original post, which is to place files in the right lib folders for the other stuff.  So, neither helps.  The question is what can I do for pulling model from a template like I can do with controller and view templates.  I see the generator code - I had a replicated copy for changing in the lib/templates/rails/model folder already - I cannot figure out what changes can be made to this to let it pull a template in, or if that's at all possible.